# DropDownList Setting Default Value

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

How should I get a value displayed in the DropDownList when redirected through a cancel buttton. The value in the page where cancel button is there in a TextBox should be caught in the DropDownList.

This DropDownList has `SelectedIndexChanged` event also fired for which on selection of a country in the list we get a ListView displayed in the same page. In that ListView we have an add button which will redirect us to another page called addcountry in which we have few controls. In those controls one TextBox I am getting value through QueryString in an enabled `False` state. Now again I need that value displayed in the DropDownList when I click cancel button.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using `$_POST` and `$_GET` Variables you should be able to retreive almost any value from a form and put it in the right place on a new page, this right place can be one of your drop down list element...

To make absolutly sure your Cancel Button will send the good value to the right page put it in an independant form that has your new page (where you have yout dropdown list) as its action, and in this seperate form put an hidden field that holds the specific value you wanna see in this dd list ...

Hope I am clear but starting with your very "fuzzy" and blur question It is hard to help you.